# How to fetch values by their keys from a child snapshot in firebase realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch values related to a particular key from the data received in my `snapshot`. This is my code:

```
dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("output",child.getValue().toString());
        }
})
```

My `output` is like this:

```
{"name"="abc", "age"=23, "height"="156 cm"}
```

I want to fetch the value with the key `height`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is my usually way when i get data from firebase.
First, create a class for store data, ex

```
class User() {
    String name;
    int age;
    int height;

    public User(){}

    public User(String name, int age, int height)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height= height;
    }

    // in case you just want to get height
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Then when you getting a snapshot

```
dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = child.getValue(User.class);
            Log.d("output", user.getHeight());
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the value of the grandchild with the key `height` of the parent solved the issue:

```
Log.d("output",child.child("height").getValue(String.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

The child variable must have a getHeight() method inside it. Try like this. :)

Comment: There is no such method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).